# How to contact concrete app users with Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-analytics

I have Firebase Crashlytics and Firebase Analytics integrated in my Android app distributed in Google Play. I know i can customize crash logs by [setting user identifier](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?platform=android#set-user-ids) as follows:

```
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setUserId(/* random unique value */)
```

Since the crash can be hardly reproduced intentionally and specific hardware + OS version is needed it's extremely important to be able to contact the owners of such devices somehow. The point is to be able to upload an alpha version to Google Play and ask those users to retest.

Can user identifier be used to reach those users somehow?

Can [Firebase in-app messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging) be used somehow to target those users?

Is it possible if distributing alpha via [Firebase App Distribution](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution)?

It requires manual stacktraces analysis to find such cases so i can't just request for user email for every crash.

Answer (score 0):

User identifiers anonymize all privately identifiable information, and so does Google Analytics with Audience data.

You can use App Distribution to send out staging/Alpha versions of your app to designated testers, and have them provide feedback/debug that way.

Comment: It will send the notifications to all the users and i need to address few specific users only

Comment: You should be able to set that up with FCM https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options. Also, the App Distribution team is working on notifications for when new builds are available for the tester to install.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean? Let's say i know the user id to contact too - let's say i generate it in the app and send it with Firebase Crashlytics log or event (key/user property). Now i need to send a message to that user with that id. Do you advice to use "FCM Data message" and let the app receive it and just ignore the message if it's received by wrong user? How can i forward it to the right user only?

Comment: You need to have access to the devices token, and then you can specify the message to be sent only to them. Here's the exact link on how to do this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-specific-devices